# Agda type error

Tags: agda

I am new to Agda, and I am attempting to define a constant `prod` of type:
    `Z → (Z → ((Z → Set) → Set))`

Now, I have written the following Agda code:

```
data Prod (X : Set) : ℕ → X where 
prod : ℕ → (ℕ → ((ℕ → X) → X))
```

When I type-check it, agda produces this error message:

```
X != Set (_33 X_) of type Set 
when checking the definition of Prod
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data type definition has two problems. Firstly, all data types are in `Set` (of some level), you can't just go around and declare data types as being elements of some other type.

```
data T : ℕ where
```

This definition tries to postulate that there's another element of the natural numbers, namely `T`. That doesn't make much sense. The only possible "type" to which you can add more elements is `Set` - the type of all (small) types. (I'm glossing over the fact that there's an infinite hierarchy of `Set`s, you shouldn't need to deal with that now).

So this is okay:

```
data T : Set where
```

---

The second problem with your definition is that the type of the `prod` constructor doesn't reflect that it really constructs something of type `Prod`. The point of constructors is that they can be an element of the type you are defining.

Let's take a look at the definition of natural numbers:

```
data ℕ : Set where
  zero : ℕ
  suc  : ℕ → ℕ
```

When we write `zero : ℕ`, we are saying that `zero` is a natural number. What if we had this instead:

```
data ℕ : Set where
  zero : String
  suc  : ℕ → ℕ
```

We are defining natural numbers and we define that `zero` is a `String`? So, since we are defining constructors, the type we give to it must mention the type we are defining in the last position. (This mention can also be indirect).

```
Op₂ : Set → Set
Op₂ A = A → A → A

data Tree (A : Set) : Set where
  nil  :          Tree A
  node : A → Op₂ (Tree A)
```

---

You can add *parameters* to the left of the colon, you cannot change those in the constructors. So for example, this is invalid:

```
data T (A : Set) : Set where
  t : T ℕ
```

Notice that `T` alone is not enough - it's not a type, but something like function from types to types (i.e. `Set → Set`). This one is okay:

```
data T (A : Set) : Set where
  t : T A
```

To the right of the colon are *indices*. These are something like parameters, except that you can choose the value in the constructors. For example, if we have a data type indexed by natural number, such as:

```
data T : ℕ → Set where
```

You can have constructors like:

```
data T : ℕ → Set where
  t₀ : T zero
  t₁ : T (suc zero)
```

Much like above, `T` alone is not a type. In this case it's a function `ℕ → Set`.

---

Anyways, back to your code. If you meant `Prod` to contain one function of type `ℕ → (ℕ → ((ℕ → X) → X))`, then it should be:

```
data Prod (X : Set) : ℕ → Set where
  prod : (ℕ → (ℕ → ((ℕ → X) → X))) → Prod X zero
```

However, I have no idea what was your intention with the index.

Comment: Back to my question, I wanted to define some sort of abbreviation or a constant that refer to this type. Now that I have read your answer, I realize that a new datatype will not do the job.. SO, I thought of functions and I have written the following and it works: prod = {X : Set} → ℕ → (ℕ → ((ℕ → X) → X)) but I do not know how to use it if I want to use to define lemmas

Comment: @ymmagdi: Well, since types are first class in Agda, you can have function taking and returning types, so that's indeed possible. Take a look at the `Op₂` function above, for example. As for how to use it - well, that's hard to say without knowing what you want to do; if you get stuck, consider asking another question (that's better than dealing with that in comments) and I'll see if I can help.